# How to include update query in azure devops release pipeline

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If we have added one new columns in a particular table and when we run the release pipeline in azure devops we need to execute an update query to update default value to the newly added column.

How can we do that?

How its possible using  sql query file?

anybody can help??

Answer (score 1):

Just use the SQL Server database deploy task
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

make sure your SQL script includes a check for if the column already exists or the job will fail

Comment: Thanks for the reply............ I have created a Visual studio SQL project. Whatever changes I am doing in tables and Store procedures are reflecting when I am deploying the dacpac. I have created one Script.PostDeployment.sql file in my Visual studio SQL project and added some update query something like "update SRC_Test set Phone='0474123456' where Id=1". This update query not working while using release pipeline.

Comment: Are you sure the script is marked as a post deployment script? Check the action that is set for it on the project. Can you share your project file?